# How to test try/except block with pytest and cover all exceptions

Tags: python, pytest, try-except, python-responses

I have a function call an api to get an access token :

```
def get_token():
    try:
        url = 'https://call-api/accesstoken'
        token = 'authentication-token'
        headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % token}
        session = requests.Session()
        response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
        return response.json()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
```

I want to test this function with pytest and verify the try/except block.
Here is my test function :

```
import responses
import functions as m_functions

@responses.activate
def test_get_token():

    url = 'https://call-api/accesstoken'
    
    responses.add(responses.GET, url, 
        json = {
                "accessToken": "tmp-token1"
                })
    
    response = m_functions.get_token()
    assert response['accessToken'] == 'tmp-token1'
```

The part inside the block try is tested, but how to test the exceptions part ?
For the moment, only part inside try block is covered by tests. I would like my code to be fully covered.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to testing but: why do you print a message and return `None` in case of an error? What is the caller supposed to do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [documentation](https://github.com/getsentry/responses/blob/3d83a88382bf5cedefbbab3986bbfeeb07883fac/README.rst#exception-as-response-body), you can specify an exception as the response body for the request to trigger an exception:

```py
responses.add(responses.GET, url, body=SomeExceptionObject(...))
```

Therefore, you can make two tests: one where you specify `HTTPError` as the exception and another tests with a different exception. You can then use the [`capsys` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/capture.html) to capture the standard output.